# Do i need to recompile the whole linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

If I change some part or some subsystem of Linux kernel, do I have to recompile the whole kernel?  Is there any way to recompile only that particular subsystem?

Answer (score 5):

If you have compiled once already, then recompiling does not build and compile the whole kernel again because kernel build system uses Makefiles which in turn follows incremental build.So, the modules you have changed recently will only be built along with some relevant files which will not take much time

Answer (score 2):

You can build parts of kernel tree (here `drivers/media`) e.g. by `make M=drivers/media`.  When using `modules_install` target you have to take that modules will be installed into `/lib/modules/<release>/extra/`.

For more information see `Documentation/kbuild/`